# What is redundant in a Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC)?

Tags: language-agnostic, crc

I'm familiar with the concept of redundant information, i.e. information that is contained in other parts of data. But I don't understand **what exactly is *redundant* in a CRC**. Can anyone shed light on the reason for the terminology?

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) is an explanation

Comment: Hmmm. That Wikipedia entry says *redundant* means that it is computable from the data. But that holds true for *any* checksum, even parity bits. A term that applies to everything is meaningless; then it could as well be named Cyclic Check...

Comment: One might also complain about the use of "redundancy" vs. "redundant".  The way it is written (which is correct) makes it sound like you are checking the redundancy.  Which you are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All check values are redundant, in that they can be computed from the message.  So by definition they add no new information to the message, and are therefore redundant.

Comment: So the word Redundancy is redundant, which is why it is called redundancy. Hofstadter might call it meta redundant, I guess :-)